# Calling Matlab from Java for heavy algorithms?

Tags: java, matlab, jakarta-ee

Did anyone made a coupling between Java and Matlab and can advise how this can be done best? Is there eg a framework that I should not miss to look at?

I want to write a java program that hands parameters to a matlab function and gets the result (and pictures created in matlab based on iterations) back.

Further these results shall be displayed on a website, so Java EE JSF will be my choice.

How can this coupling be done best?

Comment: if you want to make webapp maybe you should have a look at this http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16305-varargservlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try JAMAL (JAva MAtlab Linking): http://jamal.khadkevich.org/about.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Mathworks have made a coupling between Java and Matlab and can advise how this can be done best.  You might start your reading at [this page](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/07/06/calling-java-from-matlab/).

Comment: The OP is asking how to call Matlab from Java, Mathworks documentation only speaks about calling Java from Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

[matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com) is a Java API which will allow you to call MATLAB from Java. You can either call MATLAB from within MATLAB or from outside MATLAB in which case an instance of MATLAB is launched and connected to. It allows for invoking eval and feval in MATLAB and returning the results to MATLAB. The [walkthrough](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough) explains with examples how to do this. The walkthrough uses built-in MATLAB functions and commands, but you can use it with your own .m files because using matlabcontrol is just like interacting with MATLAB's Command Window.